# There is a linear, continuous operator $\widetilde\varphi: H \to F$ that extends $\varphi$ and preserves the norm

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $F$ a Banach space, $G$ a
> subspace of $H$ and $\varphi: G \to F$ a linear and continuous operator. Show that there is a continuous linear operator $\widetilde\varphi: H \to F$ that extends $\varphi$ and preserves the norm.

My attempt was:

Since $H$ is a Hilbert space, then $H$ is a normed space. Furthermore, since $F$ is a Banach space, $G$ is a subspace of $H$, and $\varphi:G\to F$ is a continuous linear operator, then **there is a unique continuous linear extension of $\varphi$ to the close of $G$**. Furthermore, **the norm of this extension coincides with the norm of $\varphi$**.
These statements about my hypotheses I have concluded from known results. However, how can I show that **there is a linear, continuous operator $\widetilde\varphi: H \to F$ that extends $\varphi$ and preserves the norm?**

What is the relation between the closure of $G$ and $H$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take your question as starting point and assume that $G$ is a closed subspace of $H$. The crucial property here is that closed subspaces of a Hilbert space are complemented: Every element of $H$ can be written uniquely as $x+y$ with $x\in G$ and $y\in G^\perp$. Let $\tilde \varphi(x+y)=\varphi(x)$. This map is clearly linear and
$$
\|\tilde\varphi(x+y)\|=\|\varphi(x)\|\leq\|\varphi\|\|x\|\leq\|\varphi\|(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2)^{1/2}=\|\varphi\|\|x+y\|.
$$
Thus $\|\tilde\varphi\|\leq\|\varphi\|$. Since $\tilde\varphi$ coincides with $\varphi$ on $G$, the reverse inequality follows.

Comment: Ok. I got your point. But I have two questions: Is the closed information necessary? (Yeah, for your proof, it is. I mean, I think the hypothesis is already completed.) 
The other question is : is your $\widetilde{\varphi}$ the same function that I mentioned that is unique?

Comment: Maybe that was not clear enough: You first extend $\varphi$ to the closure of $G$ as you described in your question. Then you do what I described in my answer. The extension you mentioned is only defined on the closure of $G$, not all of $H$. In general, $\tilde\varphi$ is not unique at all (you have a lot of choice to define it on $G^\perp$ without increasing the norm).

Comment: Oh, I understand now! You took $G$ as already being the closure of $G$. Very smart!
Just a last question: isn't $(||x||^2+||y||^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq ||x+y||$?

Comment: In this case, $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal, so that $\|x+y\|^2=\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2+2\mathrm{Re}\langle x,y\rangle=\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2$.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! :D